# Jboss 7.1 Database Query Hangs

Tags: jndi, jboss7.x

I earlier used Jboss 4.2.2 and recently I have installed Jboss 7.1 on linux machine. It runs fine on staging server but I am facing strange issue on production.

After a few hours of startup, my database queries start hanging. Result doesnt come back from database. I am using JNDI defined in standalone.xml.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/MyDatabaseDS" pool-name="MyDatabaseDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://host:3306/database?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;cacheServerConfiguration=true&amp;useConfigs=maxPerformance</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>user_name</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
                <timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>50000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                </timeout>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

Please help.

Comment: What do the JBoss logs say?  The MySQL logs?  The system "messages" log? Can you do an ad hoc query to mysql when the hang occurs?  Does JBoss itself appear to be hanging?  What about the JVM?  Have you tried examining it under JConsole?  From JMX-Console?

Comment: I have my logs and they print time taken in query. It slowly increases and after 7-8 hours it goes upto 5 seconds for just a simple select from a table in which there is only one row. After that logs are showing only the statements before hitting database. That clearly means that result is not coming back. Mysql Logs say nothing as the same application ran good in JBoss4.2.

Comment: Can you check on the MySQL database and check what is happening there while the application is stuck? A great place to start would be to examine the MySQL Administrator Tool's "Server Connections" page. Are there any connections? If there are, what activity is there on them? Are the expected queries running at all?

Comment: Alternatively, this could be related to slowly running out of memory. Check the amount of free available memory with top before restarting JBoss and after (or vice-versa). Compare the amount of memory used, see which process hogs it, if any.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Cant check memory snapshot as I dont know when it is going to restart. It may also be a problem of Jboss Threads.

Comment: ahh.. just a question.. are there any chances that the production JBoss server and the database are located on different/slower servers..and there is like some noticible lags?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have definitive solution to your problem, following are few things you can do to further isolate the problem:

- Monitor database performance and throughput. Since you mention the problem only happen on production, maybe it's load-related. Maybe your transaction is exclusively locking too many objects for too long hence when usage load starts peaking, the next transactions have to wait until the previous ones finished first
- Monitor server hardwares, the next time 'hanging' occurs, pay attention if CPU / memory / disk usage spikes
- Observe what other activity occurs on the database during the 'hanging', if any heavy lifting job were done maybe this will slow down your app significantly
- Perform load testing on your test / staging environment against similar production load. If you can reproduce the 'hanging' symptoms then maybe your code has scalability problem